# SVG element produced by JavaScript script jumps out from the div

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have created GANTT chart using D3 Gannt Chart (http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641). I embed it to an div that I wish to position as following:

```
        <div id="gantt" class="container">
            <div id="gantt-deep">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/gantt-chart-d3v2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gantt.js"></script>   
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that when I run the code the SVG created by the script jumps out of the div as seen in the following code when looked in Firefox:

```
<div id="gantt" class="container">
<div id="gantt-deep">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="js/lib/gantt-chart-d3v2.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="js/gantt.js" type="text/javascript">
</div>
</div>
<svg class="chart" width="990" height="490">
    <g class="gantt-chart" width="990" height="490" transform="translate(150, 20)">
</svg>
```

My question is how do I position that svg element that is created?

Comment: what you want? You question is ambiguous.

Comment: Exactly as answered below. It is not ambiguous. If you are not a expert programmer it might be hard to formulate the question, but even poorly formulated questions need answers, so that other people in same position can get a grasp of the real problem at hand, which was brought to light by Voreny. The problem was that I did not have knowledge of how SVG elements are embedded in the gantt-chart-d3v2.js script, I assumed that they would be created in the same div as the script lies automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In *gnatt-chart-d3v2.js* that was included in the example you provided there's the following line:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("class", "chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("class", "gantt-chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
```

From what I can tell this appends an svg element to the body. That's why the svg "jumps" out of your div - because it is appended to the body, not inserted where you include the script tags.

A possible solution to this would be to change *"body"* to whatever element you want to append the svg to, in your case it would be `#gantt-deep`, as you want to target the div with id *gantt-deep*.

This is a one-time solution, because it modifies the source code which doesn't allow for inserting an svg wherever. If you need another chart then you'd have to pass in a parameter to that `gnatt` function to indicate where you want it.

Actually, here's the modified version of *gnatt-chart-d3v2.js*:

```
// some code here
function gantt(tasks, element) {    // modified this line

    initTimeDomain();
    initAxis();

    var svg = d3.select(element)    // modified this line
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("class", "gantt-chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
    // leave the rest untouched
```

And then when you initiate the chart call the function with another parameter, for instance `gantt(tasks, "#gantt-deep");`

I didn't test this, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this looks just what I was wondering about. I will test this and let you know the results

Comment: @RaimoGIS No problem :)